# Using Flask-Mail to send Email through Gmail- socket.gaierr

Tags: python, flask, flask-mail

I am building a simple contact page using Flask and Flask-Mail. I built the app following this tutorial - [Add a contact page](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/intro-to-flask-adding-a-contact-page/?search_index=1) - and now when I try to send the message I receive the eror `gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`. I have been googling the error for a while and can't find any similar examples on line. I can't even figure out what name or service it can't find.

The traceback page will let me expand a row and execute some Python code. It provides a `dump()` function that will show me all the variables and can be called on objects to see their info if that will help.

routes.py :

```
from forms import ContactForm
from flask.ext.mail import Message, Mail


mail = Mail()
app = Flask(__name__)


app.secret_key = 'development key'

app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.google.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'email'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'password'

mail.init_app(app)
@app.route('/contact', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():
    form = ContactForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not form.validate():
```

the form:

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form, validators
from wtforms.fields import TextField, TextAreaField, SubmitField
import wtforms


class ContactForm(Form):
    name = TextField("Name", [wtforms.validators.Required('Please enter your name')])
    email = TextField("Email", [wtforms.validators.Required('Please enter your email'), wtforms.validators.Email()])
    subject = TextField("Subject", [wtforms.validators.Required('Please enter a subject')])
    message = TextAreaField("Message", [wtforms.validators.Required('Please enter a message')])
    submit = SubmitField("Send")
            flash('All fields are required.')
            return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
        else:
            msg = Message(form.subject.data, sender='imauld@gmail.com', recipients=['imauld@gmail.com'])
            msg.body = """From: %s &lt;%s&gt; %s""" % (form.name.data, form.email.data, form.message.data)
            mail.send(msg)
            return render_template('contact.html', success=True)
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
```

the traceback:

```
File "/home/ian/PycharmProjects/flaskapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__

return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

File "/home/ian/PycharmProjects/flaskapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app

response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))

File "/home/ian/PycharmProjects/flaskapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception

reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "/home/ian/PycharmProjects/flaskapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app

response = self.full_dispatch_request()

File "/home/ian/PycharmProjects/flaskapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request

rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

File "/home/ian/PycharmProjects/flaskapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception

reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "/home/ian/PycharmProjects/flaskapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request

rv = self.dispatch_request()

File "/home/ian/PycharmProjects/flaskapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request

return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

File "/home/ian/PycharmProjects/flaskapp/app/routes.py", line 39, in contact

mail.send(msg)

File "/home/ian/PycharmProjects/flaskapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 415, in send

with self.connect() as connection:

File "/home/ian/PycharmProjects/flaskapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 123, in __enter__

self.host = self.configure_host()

File "/home/ian/PycharmProjects/flaskapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 135, in configure_host

host = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(self.mail.server, self.mail.port)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 776, in __init__

SMTP.__init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 249, in __init__

(code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 309, in connect

self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 781, in _get_socket

new_socket = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection

for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):

gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have the following settings that work for me

```
app.config['MAIL_SERVER']='smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'xx@gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'xx;'
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
```

Note that MAIL_USE_TLS parameter that I have. Also not sure if it matters but your MAIL_SERVER is set to smtp.google.com while mine is smtp.gmail.com.

**EDIT**: As confirmed, the primary issue was that your smtp host was incorrectly set. It should always be `smtp.gmail.com`

Comment: Since the error is about not being able to find the host, I'm guessing your last point is spot on.

Comment: It was. That's what I get for working on this until past my bedtime.